# KeyError:"Corrections" while parsing text using GingerIt in python on text data in pandas

Tags: python, text-processing, spell-checking

```
##!pip install gingerit

from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt
jd = []
for txt in list(data['Job Description']):
   jd.append(GingerIt().parse(txt)['result'])
data['jd'] = jd
```

I want to correct the spelling and grammatical mistakes in a text feature/column in a pandas dataframe which has ~3000 rows. Each row contains 4-5 statements. So, I used GingerIt() from gingerit.gingerit and I am getting an error.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-ea5c757d88d2> in <module>()
     5           jd = []
     6           for txt in list(datajd['Job Description']):
---->7           jd.append(GingerIt().parse(txt)['result'])


/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gingerit/gingerit.py in parse(self, text, verify)
      26         )
      27         data = request.json()
 ---> 28         return self._process_data(text, data)
      29 
      30     @staticmethod

 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gingerit/gingerit.py in _process_data(self, text, data)
      38         corrections = []
      39 
 ---> 40         for suggestion in reversed(data["Corrections"]):
      41             start = suggestion["From"]
      42             end = suggestion["To"]

 KeyError: 'Corrections'
```

Comment: Can you share the part of your dataframe?  I do not get the issue. If your code works with simple data (did you try on a toy example?), the problem is in the data.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is the link to the dataset - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nMOBIe4xeT68-VPnNBoi7TD4tentz_68/view?usp=sharing
Please refer the column "Job Description". 
I did try it on a toy example taking only a simple sentence and it was working fine. 
Your help will be very much appreciated. 

Thank you

Comment: Ginger free plan has a char limit on sentences, thus you need to "skip" longer sentences, or subsegment them. What would you prefer? What should be the fallback process?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perhaps, it will be better to segment the statements at every end of sentence.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is it also possible to get ambiguous features using TfidfVectorizer after correcting the spelling mistakes?

Comment: Not every sentence detected with Python tools is short enough for Ginger. It requires some more specific rules to subsegment sentences.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you send a reference link?

Comment: Not sure what link you mean. BTW, Ginger is so slow, I tried to run it on your file yesterday  (with omitting the too long sentences) and it did not finish even after a couple of hours.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried to clean that feature using TextBlob and pyspellchecker, all these methods take a lot of time to execute. What method will you suggest to clean the feature?

Comment: Given the current question, I can only suggest you the code to use Ginger for sentences that are short enough to be processed and leave the long sentences unprocessed.

Answer (score 1):

`GingerIt` has a paid Premium service based on API keys, so the free version cannot deal with sentences of more than 300 chars.

You can use a sentence segmenter of your choice, here, you can use[`pysb` Pragmatic Sentence Boundary Disambiguation module](https://github.com/nipunsadvilkar/pySBD) (install it with `pip install pysbd`). Then, run the sentences with length less than 300 chars through Ginger and join the results.

If you can have long sentences and you still want to handle them, make sure you further subsegment the sentences. Here, I suggest a regex like `[^;:\n•]+[;,:\n•]?\s*` that subsegments on `;`, `:`, newline and a bullet point, but you may add more chars you need.

```py
from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt # pip install gingerit
import pandas as pd
import pysbd, re # pip install pysbd

file  = r'test.csv'

segmentor = pysbd.Segmenter(language="en", clean=False)
data = pd.read_csv(file)

subsegment_re = r'[^;:\n•]+[;,:\n•]?\s*'

def runGinger(par):
    fixed = []
    for sentence in segmentor.segment(par):
        if len(sentence) < 300:
            fixed.append(GingerIt().parse(sentence)['result'])
        else:
            subsegments = re.findall(subsegment_re, sentence)
            if len(subsegments) == 1 or any(len(v) < 300 for v in subsegments):
                # print(f'Skipped: {sentence}') // No grammar check possible
                fixed.append(sentence)
            else:
                res = []
                for s in subsegments:
                    res.append(GingerIt().parse(s)['result'])
                fixed.append("".join(res))
    return " ".join(fixed)

data['jd'] = data['Job Description'].apply(lambda x: runGinger(x))
```